# FirebirdSQL: глобальный псевдоним для таблицы или столбца?

Tags: firebird, psql, interbase

Я работаю с огромной базой данных Firebird, в которой таблицы имеют совершенно нечитаемые имена, такие как `WTF$RANDOM_ABBREVIATION_6792` или `RPG$RANDOM_ABBREVIATION_5462`, где столбцы имеют такие имена, как «`rid9312`», «`1NUM5`», «`2NUM4»`, «`RNAME8`».

Мне нужно установить для них глобальные псевдонимы, чтобы использовать их как нормальные имена таблиц, вроде `Document`, а также имена столбцов:

`Document.CreationDate` вместо `xecblob.DDATE4` или

`TempDoc.MovingOrderID` вместо `TMP$LINKED_DOC_6101.DID6101`

Изменение базы данных, таблицы или столбца (Alter Table) может быть большой проблемой, потому что записей в базе миллионы, и более того, большая часть написанного на Delphi интерфейса для базы данных, привязана к именам таблиц и столбцов.

Реально ли как-то создать подобные глобльные alias'ы?

*update: [аналог вопроса на англоязычном форуме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835699/set-a-global-alias-for-a-table-and-a-column/70836046#70836046)*

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70835699/5376639

Answer (score 1):

На [англоязычном форуме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835699/set-a-global-alias-for-a-table-and-a-column/70836046#70836046) я нашёл ответ – просто сделать *create view*.

```
create view document
as
select 
  DDATE4 as creationdate
  -- , other columns...
from xecblob;
```

или

```
create view document (creationdate /*, other column aliases... */)
as
select 
  DDATE4
  -- , other columns...
from xecblob;
```

(personally, I find the first variant more readable)

Для этого придётся изменить базу данных, но без каких-либо затрат памяти, ресурсов, и т.д. (не важно, сколько в таблице записей).

Comment: По идее это было сделано с целью обфускации БД. Подумайте, вам нужно выставлять наружу реальную структуру?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, ну и ещё с целью запудрить голову людям, которые читают имена таблиц и пытаются работать с базой на каком-то другом языке, отличном от мной невероятно любимого Delphi. Удивительно прекрасный язык, любимый комьюнити разработчиков за его старинные корни и большое количество разнообразного кода, который, кстати, мне необходимо поддерживать (2002-го выпуска с компонентами такой же давности).